# Почему пропадают файлы с флешки?

Tags: windows, файловая-система

Данная флешка использовалась в автомобиле какое-то время. Сегодня утром, после проблем с аккумулятором, имею такое:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Стёрлась. В зависимости какие сектора выпали - инфу можно восстановить или невозможно. Есть даже услуги платного восстановления данных. Проще всего переформатировать. Из утилит восстановления назову две Acronics, и DiskEdit (вторая очень слабая). Процесс восстановления не простой.

Comment: Recuva попробуй.

Comment: А ещё есть вариант с вирусом и скрытыми файлами. Консоль и chkdsk могут что-то подсказать.

Comment: Ну так вы сами ответили из-за траблов с аккумулятором. Автомобильная сеть рачитана на напряжение где-то 11-14,5v, а микроконтроллер флешки думаю очень чуствителен к скачкам. Некачественная аудиотехника иногда плохо переваривает напряжение машины получаются такие глюки. Я бы попробовал Low Level Format утилиты

Comment: Проводник виндовый - не показатель ни разу. Он может показывать не все файлы как минимум. Ну и еще с пяток причин, по которым такое может быть, так что гадание на кофейной гуще, увы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не согласен. Вернее не полностью. Если бы файлы были удалены (почистились заголовки), то винда бы показывала дофига свободного места.

Comment: @donRumata, не понял, с чем именно ты не согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, с использованием recuva в конкретной ситуации. Из пушки по воробьям, имхо.

Comment: @donRumata, Recuva умеет искать неудалённые файлы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я в курсе. Просто смысл качать целую прогу, если есть встроенные средства?

Comment: @donRumata, ну она обычно уже стоит. По крайней мере, у меня. Кстати, а для пары соседних вопросов встроенные средства не подскажешь? [Двоеточие](/q/572677/178988) и [кавычки](/q/586607/178988) :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, я не против программы, тем более если она бесплатная. А если ещё и свободная - так вообще шик. Просто для обычного проигрывания dvd-дисков люди ставили полную ломаную версию `powerdvd` или для записи cd всё, что входило в пакет `nero`. И конкретно в данном вопросе я не вижу смысла ей пользоваться, потому что проблема из другой области.

Comment: @donRumata, судя по результату - проблема была всё-таки не в вирусе. Возможно, она дала бы лучший результат, чем кучка файлов без нормальных имён...

Answer (score 1):

Классическая проблема после вируса-прятальщика.

Открыть `cmd`

```
F:

attrib -S -H /S /D
```

Эта команда поменяет атрибуты на файлы, снимет с них атрибут "системный" и "скрытый".

Comment: Вот, что вышло: http://i.imgur.com/77bT2Ca.png
Попробую в приемника атомобильном запустить, хотя выглядит странно )

Comment: @Anhk, http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=11:34177 . Значит не вирус. Просто хреновый порт, хреновая память внутри флэшки, хреновый контроллер в магнитоле, хреновое питание на порт. Выбирай любой.

Comment: Не факт, что не вирус. Тут есть нюанс...

Comment: @Qwertiy, после скриншота теперь я склоняюсь больше к проблемам софта и питания. Но всё равно такую комбинацию глюков встречаю первый раз (опять же беря во внимание скриншот выше).

Comment: Если погуглить, то попадается, что chkdsk делал такое после вируса.

Comment: http://acid.name/?p=108

Answer (score 1):

Для файловой системы FAT32 количество занятого пространства подсчитывается исходя из сведений по использованным кластерам из таблиц FAT. Отсутствие файлов в проводнике говорит либо о том, что они скрытые/системные, а отображение таких не включено, либо о том, что имеются проблемы в файловой системе (потерянные кластеры). Ну или и то, и другое.

Судя по именам отображаемых файлов на позднем скриншоте, в файловой системе были ошибки (если был сбой по питанию - это запросто), и над диском уже в компьютере поработал chkdsk (напрасно Вы разрешили ему полечить носитель или не запретили этого, ведь не зря его зовут диск-дестроером). Огорчу - структура каталогов и имена файлов потеряны безвозвратно. Содержимое многих файлов верное, но дополненное до кластера (т.е. имеется паразитный "хвост") - в подавляющем большинстве случаев это нестрашно. Если там было что-то важное, есть шанс разобраться.

Рекомендую переместить это всё на жёсткий диск для дальнейшего разбирательства, если оно нужно, конечно, а флешку переформатировать в NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по позднему скриншоту, дело явно не в вирусе, который прячет файлы, но на всякий случай я выложу своё решение, вдруг кому-то понадобится. У этого вируса есть две модификации. Первый просто делает эти файлы скрытыми и системными, а другой перемещает их в каталог `e2e2~1`, который не отображается ни в проводнике Windows, ни в других файловых менеджерах. Для лечения обеих модификаций я разработал скрипт, который нужно записать на флешку, запустить и следовать подсказкам. [Скачать скрипт](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6-EUY_yhrlRMnNlYVhFcTR3c1k). Не публикую листинг здесь из-за возможных проблем с кодировкой.